# how to set configuration of log4cpp for visual studio 2008

Tags: c++, logging, log4cxx, log4cpp

i want to use **log4cpp** library in my code for logging. But,for windows platform i dont know how to configure the library. I am using **Visual Studio 2008.**
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use the workspace and project files in subdirectory msvc8. (You may need to adjust include/log4cpp/config-win32.h and the project files to your particular needs).

You may also opt for compilation of source using cygwin and call exported functions from library.

Comment: i want to use this library on windows platform not on linux.

Comment: cygwin  provides library which work on windows environment. you can use exported functions in your code by loading dll.

Comment: There are also the following alternatives:
1) Apache's log4cxx which is still active.
2) Matthew Wilson's Pantheios library.
3) Log4cplus.